# Transparent AppBar in material-ui (React)

Tags: material-ui

Is there a way to change the background property of my material-ui `AppBar` component to transparent without having to actually change the CSS?

I've tried the opacity property, but that reduces the opacity of everything within the component it seems.

Below is an example of what I mean on Stripe's website.

[image]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can change its background color to transparent and remove the box-shadow this way:

```
<AppBar position="static"  style={{ background: 'transparent', boxShadow: 'none'}}>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that without it being inline?

Comment: Another way could be creating a custom theme, but if everything else is ok for you in the built-in themes except the appbar background, the above one is the quickest solution

Comment: Ok. I was trying to use a `styles` variable at the top of my file that holds the `AppBar` component, and then use `export default withStyles(styles)(AppBarComponentHere)` for some reason that didn't work no matter what I tried.

Comment: Did your appBar class look like this?  I got this working.

     appBar: {
        background: 'transparent',
        boxShadow: 'none'
     },

Comment: I was looking to where this was. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 33):

```html
<AppBar color="transparent" elevation={0}>
```

Comment: From the doc https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/ and https://material-ui.com/api/paper/

Comment: Thanks, `Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element (Paper).`

Comment: Much better solution than accepted answer

Comment: Perfect, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The inline styles do the trick, so thanks for that. But I felt a little uncomfortable with the approach since we wouldn't normally use inline styles--with or without React.

I delved a little deeper to try to find something that fits more with the framework, and this is what I came up with.

```
// in App.js
const GlobalCss = withStyles({
  '@global': {
    '.MuiAppBar-root': {
      background: 'transparent',
      boxShadow: 'none'
    }
  }
})(() => null)
```

The tag then needs to be inserted into the markup, which for me is:

```
<div>
  <GlobalCss />
  <Router>
    .
    .
    .
```

The relevant parts of the documentation are:

- CSS rules to override, at [AppBar API > CSS](https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/#css);
- setting global CSS, at [Global CSS override](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-css-override).