# Classname doesn't override the root style of AppBar

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to change the style of the AppBar component using `className` but the `.MuiAppBar-root` is always followed.

```js
const useBoardStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: 'black',
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1
  },

const classes = useBoardStyles();

...
<AppBar position='fixed' className={classes.appBar} >
```

[image]

Here it shows `.makeStyles-appBar-139` is overridden by `.MuiAppBar-colorPrimary` for `background-color` and `color` and by `.MuiAppBar-root` for `z-index`.

I also tried to use `classes`

```js
<AppBar position='fixed' classes={{ root: styles.appBar }} >
```

and still the same.

**Edit :** I'm using typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your CSS("makeStyles-appBar") is applied last compare to "MuiAppBar-colorPrimary" which is default,

Couple of solution for your case,

## 1. use style property

```
<AppBar position="fixed"  style={{ color: 'black', z-index: 1201, background-color: 'red'}}>
```

## 2. use !important on your css - not advisable

```
appBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'red !important',
    color: 'black !important',
    zIndex: (theme.zIndex.drawer + 1) + ' !important'
}
```

reference - 
[Transparent AppBar in material-ui (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117231/transparent-appbar-in-material-ui-react)

https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/

## TypeScript  - with decorators refer like below,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withStyles, WithStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { StyledComponent } from 'material-ui';

type C = 'root' | 'foo';

interface P { options?: string[]; }

interface S { open: boolean; }

@withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {},
  foo: {},
}))
class Component extends React.Component<P & WithStyles<C>, S> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.classes.root} />
    );
  }
}

export default Component as StyledComponent<P, C>; // type assertion
```

## without decorators

```
const SelectedMenu = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 360,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}))<P>(class extends React.Component<P & WithStyles<C>, S> {
```

Source - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8598

Comment: I'm having a problem with the first option because I'm using typescript. Sorry if I didn't mention it above. The error say something about unexpected token but I'm sure it is not about the syntax.

Comment: is it possible for you to share this exact error you are seeing - "error say something about unexpected token"

Comment: can you read this and apply the same and try? - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8598

Comment: It is working now. But I would like to know if the decorator is only used for class component? As defined here for [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). And also is `withStyles` is only the possible solution for this problem?

Comment: its the best solution as for i remember

Comment: if you are satisfied please do not forget to mark the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

navBar:{
backgroundColor: `${Theme.colors.base1} !important`,
color: `${Theme.colors.base2} !important`
},

use !important on your css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).