# How to make toolbar in material-ui transparent?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui. There are two toolbars where the second toolbar want to have transparent background

I followed this, [Transparent AppBar in material-ui (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117231/transparent-appbar-in-material-ui-react) but its for AppBar component and not working for Toolbar

My Code :

Theme Fie :

```
const MuiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
  },
  mixins: {
    toolbar: {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
    },
  },
});
```

Toolbar File

```
const toolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: theme.mixins.toolbar.backgroundColor,
  },
}));


 <AppBar position="static" style={{ boxShadow: "none" }}>
            <Toolbar className="toptoolBar">
              {/* */}
            </Toolbar>
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
              <Toolbar
                style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                classes={{ root: toolbarSt.toolbar }}
              >
                {/* */}
              </Toolbar>
            </div>
          </AppBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make only a certain number of toolbar style changes, then doing it in the theme file is not recommended. Instead, use the `makeStyles`

```
export default function App() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <AppBar position="static" style={{ boxShadow: "none" }}>
            <Toolbar classes={{root:classes.greenToolbar}} className="toptoolBar" >
                Green
            </Toolbar>
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
                <Toolbar
                    classes={{ root: classes.transparentToolbar }}>
                    transparent
                </Toolbar>
            </div>
        </AppBar>
    );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    transparentToolbar: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        color: "red"
    },
    greenToolbar:{
        backgroundColor:'green'
    }
}));
```

Here is the working demo :

[image: Edit nervous-chatelet-3cp0h]

Comment: thanks for trying but i want a transparent background

Comment: it is transparent, second toolbar is transparent.  that's why it showing the bg color of the parent which is appbar. if you change the background color of the appbar, it's bg color will also change